# Codeigniter 4 routes not working on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, codeigniter-4

I have hosted my codeigniter 4 based application on aws successfully and It's home page displaying perfectly. But any other route is not working like domain.com/admin it's displaying 404 default page of aws.

I have created a virtual host file for my domain and disabled the default virtual host file. But it's not affected the application. So, how to make this work?

Comment: Do you mean / preceded routes are not working?

Comment: @MdFarzan Yes, all other routes like /admin etc are not working

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess file with re-writing turned on such as here .. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#urls-remove-index-php-apache ??